# Strategical considerations for nested parallel computing in R with foreach

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, nested-loops

I am using the `foreach`-package in R to run some code in parallel.

Technically it works for me but the computational improvement is fairly moderate, to be honest.

Since I have limited experience with parallel computing and only found fairly outdated (or questionable) articles online, I hoped I could pick your brains on your experience in terms of strategy to improve efficiency.

The situation is as follows, I have one outer loop (multiple thousand iterations, therefore fewer cores than iterations) and multiple smaller inner loops (with iterations less than cores available). The computational demanding parts occur within the smaller inner loops.

So far, I have been running the outer loop with `foreach` and `%dopar%`; and the inner ones with standard `for`-loops.

The reasoning for that was, that if I run the inner ones in parallel instead, most cores will remain unused since the loops themselves have fewer iterations than cores available.

Please see some pseudo-code for illustration:

```
foreach(it = 1:10000, .inorder = FALSE) %dopar% {

    Some simple computations

    for(i in 1:10){

        Some demanding computation

    }

    Some more simple computations

    for(i in 1:10){

        And some more demanding computation

    }

}
```

My question is, from your experience, is it more efficient to run inner or outer loops in parallel or both and is my reasoning regarding the non-usage of cores if running the inner loops in parallel instead correct?

Just FYI, I am currently developing on an eight-core, 16 GB RAM machine but will ultimately take it to the cloud with 16 cores and 50 GB RAM.

Hope you could share your experience since I believe it is a decision other people will face occasionally as well.

Best,
Oliver

Comment: How much time does a full inner computation take? Parallel computing has the overhead of setting up the workers, and if the computation is too short, overhead will outweight gains

Comment: Currently, during the development stage, roughly 30 minutes. Later on, roughly four hours.

Comment: Is such situations, improvement should be number of workers : could you elaborate on 'fairly moderate'? Did you verify in task manager that all processors are working?

Comment: Fairly moderate meaning, running one iteration of the outer loop (obviously "sequentially") takes 35 minutes. Five iterations (with seven cores) take four hours, six minutes. I believe it might be an issue with available RAM that hinders the parallel computation to outperform. Yes, I have checked the task manager. All cores run as expected.